# Visual Studio fail to attach to C++ process on Centos?

Tags: c++, debugging, centos7

I am trying to debug a c++ process on Centos7 using Visual Studio 2017. But I am not using a Linux Project built by VS, just want to attach to remote linux process using ssh. I have done the same things on a ubuntu16.04 machine, all thing works fine, but not in this time on Centos7.when I try to attach,VS allert[can not connect to remote host,unsupport operation,unknow error 0x8004005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKcp1.png)

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you able to ssh to that machine successfully outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: yes, I can log in the centos using xshell with root user